# Can't map between Jira project and FishEye

Tags: jira, atlassian-fisheye

i have installed Jira server. i have also installed FishEye 
i have configured FishEye to see Jira installation and configured Jira to see FishEye. 
from FishEye i can see all my Git repository. problem is, that i can't access code from Jira. 
when looking at the FishEye configuration i see that the mapping section is empty... and i can't find a way to map it. 
in the Associate Project with Repository Path i see that FishEye server is configured but i can't see any repository from the drop down list. 
what did i do wrong? thanks!

Comment: i can do that only when someone answers me right?

Comment: yes, and you already got answers to some of your previous questions and you didn't accept any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restart both Jira and Fisheye.

Comment: If I could I would have deleted this answer, but as it is accepted I cannot delete it.